# KDE doesn't see plugged in external drives anymore (panel widget and Dolphin) though the system sees them

Tags: usb, kde, opensuse, plasma, exfat

My KDE Plasma (I'm running openSUSE Tumbleweed):

[image: my KDE specs]

... doesn't detect USB sticks anymore (neither in the Devices panel widget nor in Dolphin). I'm not sure if it's an exfat or general problem, all my drives are formatted in exfat right now. `exfatprogs` and `exfat-utils` are installed and up to date.

I think it's a small issue, since tools like `fdisk` and `hwinfo` **do see them** — and I can `sudo mount` them (I get a white message though: "*FUSE exfat 1.4.0 (libfuse2)*"). I thinks it's just a KDE issue, and I hope it can be solved in a few commands. I didn't find a solution online though. I tried among other things to install the `fuse-devel` pattern of packages but I get 3 errors at the end of the install, I don't know if this is relevant.

Thanks!